# SO tips & tricks

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, blog, article

Am I allowed to publish a 'SO Tips & Tricks' article on my blog that I have already written?

The article is now live at:

http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/stackoverflow-tips-tricks-5/

**Edit:**

**Hello all, thanks for your comments they clarified a lot and now i have updated the article on the site. Thanks**

Comment: Well, looks like you already did post it: http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/stackoverflow-tips-tricks-5/

Comment: Some good pointers you have there, though I'm not sure about this: "Even if you are not sure about your answer, post it....". Personally if I'm not 100% sure, either I don't post it or claim my uncertainty.

Comment: You don't get badges for closing.

Comment: Don't forget about the all important "No soulless circles/lines/shadows etc.." for images

Comment: I am going to revise the article after having a look at great answers posted by various people. thanks

Comment: The post has been converted into wiki, i should have done that initially on, sorry for that :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Super User and Server Fault have other purposes than "giving you 100 reputation". Just saying.

And besides, highly disagree with that:

> **4. Be the First to Answer a Question**
>
> If there is question you think you
>   know the answer of, jump to it
>   instantly and answer it. If you have
>   answered it correctly and are the
>   first to answer then if anyone else
>   visits that question, he may vote you
>   up rather than providing his own
>   correct answer that you have already
>   provided. Even if you are not sure
>   about your answer, post it, you can
>   modify it later on by viewing others’
>   answers that you think are correct. By
>   default, all answers are ordered by
>   number of votes, so if you manage to
>   get some votes, your answer will be on
>   top of all there by having more
>   chances of getting votes and finally
>   chosen as the final correct answer
>   something for which you earn 15
>   additional points.

Especially on Stack Overflow, answers are going **very** fast. so most of times there will be at least 2 other answers at same time as your, even if you post as fast as you can. It's not about the speed, then, it's about the quality of your answer. You can be the first to write a 4 words answer with a fast link. I will still vote for the answer which came 10 minutes later, with a detailed explanation.

And about your "answer even if not sure and correct when seeing other answer", that's stupid. You are actually promoting stealing answers and the "fastest gun in the West" behavior. You only forgot one thing:

**Nobody cares about your reputation besides you. You are not here to enlarge your reputation, you are here to give answers to people asking questions.**

In the end, nobody cares if you answered first. What matters to the person who asked, is that at the end of the day, he has his answer, a correct and complete one.

So you can write about tips for Stack Overflow, for a better use (like using ignored and favorite tags, adding pictures, etc.) But giving tips to have a better reputation, it serves no one. Besides the ego, I guess: "My reputation is bigger than yours."

Because besides that, what is the use for reputation? You gain more "powers" to help the community, to edit posts, to vote to close the questions which are not matching to the criterias, etc. Reputation only gives you more possibilities to moderate. Which means actually caring for the site, and not only about you. I don't see that matching to such "reputation" methods.

---

**Edit:** Ok, the author changed his article. The part about SF and SU is improved, inviting people to get involved in these sites as well, instead of only using them as "100 rep", good. You could also mention that most of what you write works for these sites as well (besides the code specific parts, of course).

The 4th point has been revised as well:

> **4. Be the First to Answer a Question**
>
> If there is question you think you
>   know the answer of, jump to it
>   instantly and answer it. If you have
>   answered it correctly and are the
>   first to answer then if anyone else
>   visits that question, he may vote you
>   up rather than providing his own
>   correct answer that you have already
>   provided. By default, all answers are
>   ordered by number of votes, so if you
>   manage to get some votes, your answer
>   will be on top of all there by having
>   more chances of getting votes and
>   finally chosen as the final correct
>   answer something for which you earn 15
>   additional points. Getting your answer
>   (correct one) to be first just makes
>   it more likely to get quick votes but
>   remember this is not the rule of
>   thumb, an answer posted after even
>   half an hour can be voted up and
>   chosen as the final correct answer.
>
> Another important thing is that once
>   you have posted your answer, you can
>   revise it, add more details such as
>   lists, images, etc. This shows how
>   comprehensive answer you have given
>   with examples/demos and makes your
>   answer best in the queue.

It is less inviting to answer "at all cost", good. You can emphasize more on the fact that if on the short term, the first short correct answer is getting votes, on a middle and long term, answers which are describing and explaining the most are the ones getting the most votes. I won't say that this is always like this, but most of times, a higher quality (and longer) answer will have more votes.

I would suggest you to encourage "descriptive" answers in case of a link. Even if a perfect answer can be found at a given link, a good answer on SO should include the interesting part from it as well, or at least an extract or summary, if too long. Because links are not eternal, and a great answer can be lost if the linked site goes down. Link should still be, but only as a link to the source. The point is to have the interesting data on SO.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of thing I would expect a user with only 1,423 meta rep to say. *sniff*

Comment: @Jeff - Why can't I say if you are sarcastic or not? Hmm.

Comment: @Gnoupi: +1: great explanation, you have mentioned some of the points i did not know about, i am going to revise that article, thanks man

Comment: i have updated the article after reading helpful comments here. Thanks all.

Comment: @Safraz Ahmed: Then maybe you should mark your article as community wiki.

Comment: @Denial: yeah that is nice suggestion , i forgot that should have done initially on...

Comment: @Gnoupi: the last paragraph of your comment is good and in fact i had that in my to do list when writing the article but then it slipped out of my mind. thanks

Answer (score 5):

And if it is OK with you I don't "need" to install the grease-monkey scripts (point 3). Nor in fact do I want to.

It is "Markdown", not "MarkDown" (point 5).

*Subtle* styling (to emphasize words etc) is entirely appropriate (point 6).

Only add images (point 7) *when they help the answer* - not just to make it shiny.

The 5-minute editing "cleverly" (point 10) would be interpreted by me as "gaming". Don't do 
that.

Comment: i have updated the article after reading helpful comments here. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to post tips and tricks articles.  But it may not be received well if any of your tips or tricks could be considered gaming the system.

**Edit** I scanned the article and it looks good to me.

Comment: @Justin Nelson: how did you find the article, i have not provided its link, which url are you talking about?

Comment: @Justin Nelson: Thanks for your answer, i was little worried but now i am happy that i am allowed and you like it, +1 thanks

Comment: @Sarf I went to your profile and found the link to your blog.

Comment: i have updated the article after reading helpful comments here. Thanks all.